# Cmake not linking when building sfml

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

I have my project, nested in another directory with the required libraries for my project. I'm using cmake that's bundled with Clion, 3.14. I am using subdirectories with cmake. I have it building just fine, but it's not linking SFML

Root-|
      -lib1
      -smfl
      -lib3
      -my_project

I've tried using things like using 'target_link_directories()' but either I did it wrong, or it's absolutely not the right option.

Root CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

include_directories("ChaiScript/include" Catch2/include freetype2/include SFML/include )

add_subdirectory(Catch2)
add_subdirectory(ChaiScript)
add_subdirectory(freetype2)
add_subdirectory(SFML)


add_subdirectory(Purrmaid)
```

./Purrmaid/CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
project (purrmaid)



add_executable( purrmaid
        main.cpp
        Base_Object.cpp
        ...
        ThreadManager.cpp)

target_link_libraries(purrmaid sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-network sfml-audio pthread dl)
```

```
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_MulFix'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Init_FreeType'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Char_Index'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Kerning'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Get_Glyph'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_New_Face'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_Set'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Outline_Embolden'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Load_Char'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Done_Glyph'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_New'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Open_Face'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Glyph_Stroke'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Bitmap_Embolden'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Done_Face'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_New_Memory_Face'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Stroker_Done'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Done_FreeType'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'
../SFML/lib/libsfml-graphics-d.so.2.5.1: undefined reference to `FT_Select_Charmap'
```

Comment: Right now there is no `target_link_libraries` in the code you showed. There should be.

Comment: Should there be in the Root CmakeList.txt? Also, edited.

Comment: Is `undefined reference` the **first** error you got? Probably, the linker cannot find FreeType library which is linked to `libsfml-graphics` one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error shown is that SFML cannot link because it cannot find reference to different `FT_` symbols (`FT_MulFix`, `FT_Init_FreeType`, etc.)

These are defined by the FreeType library. I assume you are building the different SFML targets when you `add_subdirectory(SFML)`

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file in the `SFML` subdirectory, do you link the `sfml-graphics` target against Free type?

```
add_library(sfml-graphics
            ...)

# This is assuming you have a "freetype2" target available
# please replace by the actual name of the freetype target
target_link_libraries(sfml-graphics freetype2 ...)
```

---

**EDIT**: Thanks to *Tsyvarev* for pointing me in the direction of the actual target that was not able to link.

Comment: A **dynamic** (`.so`) library **always** stores links to the libraries it requires. No needs to link to libraries, which are needed for *dymanic* ones.

Comment: It was actually 
```cmake
...
sfml_add_library(sfml-graphics
                 SOURCES ${SRC} ${DRAWABLES_SRC} ${RENDER_TEXTURE_SRC} ${STB_SRC})

# setup dependencies
target_link_libraries(sfml-graphics PUBLIC sfml-window freetype)
```